# Update component outside the Iframe

Tags: jsf, iframe, primefaces

I want to update a component which resides outside an iframe. I will call the update from a component that is inside the iframe and update the component that is outside the iframe. How can I do so?

```
<p:tabView id="tab_view" dynamic="true" cache="true" scrollable="true">

        <p:tab id="tab_1" title="Test">
            <iframe id="tab_frame"
                src="#{request.contextPath}/xxx/xxx.xhtml"
                width="100%" height="285px" style="border-width: 0px;" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
```

**xxx.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="testform">
    <p:commandLink value="Click here" action="#{controller.methodY()}" style="color:blue;" update="tab_view"/>
</h:form>
```

The update in commandlink does not work. How can I update my tabview?

Comment: Have you tried `update=":tab_view`? (assuming you don't have any naming container parent of tab_view)

Comment: @mrganser i tried specifying the tabview id in update attribute of the command link.

Comment: Yes, I meant to add a colon ":" just before the tabview id

Comment: i tried it but it says a component not found. Cannot find component with expression "tab_view" from...

Comment: I'm not sure then, is it possible for you to use `ui:include` instead of iframe? This way I'm sure it'll work just adding the colon, otherwise I'm clueless...

Comment: @mrganser yes ui include works. But i need to load the contents dynamically which has some dependency between pages. So i need to have lazy loading as well.

Comment: PrimeFaces doesn't have a form component !

Comment: @HatemAlimam Ok i missed it. It is from JSF. Now edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refresh component in parent from inner iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958557/refresh-component-in-parent-from-inner-iframe)