# Refresh component in parent from inner iframe

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this xhtml (primefaces) simple page:

```
....
<div id="header">
    <h:outputText value="#{userBean.name}"/>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <p:tabView value="#{appTabbedView.tabs}" var="tab" dynamic="true"
        cache="false">
        <p:tab title="#{tab.title}">
            <iframe frameborder="0" src="#{tab.page}" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</div>
.....
```

Inside the iframe, I load a p:tab which loads a page named "Profile.xhtml" which allows edit (change) the user's  name.
How can I refresh the header to show the new user's name (im inside an iframe!)?
I cant find a solution, I tried everything.

Comment: Not tested...  Surround your header div with `<h:panelGroup id="headerupd"...` and `</h:panelGroup`. In your bean you can add `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("headerupd");`

Comment: Nice idea...but it seems it doesn't work...at least in my tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution. It works!

```
....
<div id="header">
    <h:form id="formHeader">
        <p:commandLink id="hiddenLink" update="user" value="hiddenLink" style="display:none" />
        <h:outputText value="#{userBean.name}" id="user"/>
    </h:form>
</div>

<div id="content">
    <p:tabView value="#{appTabbedView.tabs}" var="tab" dynamic="true" cache="false">
        <p:tab title="#{tab.title}">
            <iframe frameborder="0" src="#{tab.page}" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
</div>
.....
```

script.js:

```
function refreshHeader() {
    window.parent.document.getElementById('formHeader:hiddenLink').click();
}
```

inside Profile.xhtml:

```
....
<p:commandButton id="accept" ... oncomplete="refreshHeader()" />
....
```

Comment: Instead of a hidden commandLink, and the need to know the id of the component in the iframe, use a `p:remoteCommand` in which you 'just' declare a javascript function.